# NodeJS Chokidar / fs issues with cloud object storage volumes mapped to docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, file-watcher, chokidar, fswatch

I am using Chokidar package in my NodeJS code and having issues with watching folders that are created in Cloud Object Storage bucket and mounted as volumes in my Runtime.
Same code is working flawlessly in my local Mac and also in on-prem linux server where the application is currently deployed.
Even with COS- Chokidar triggers once when the pod is created(so all set-up and volume mounting is correct) but after that it doesn’t pick any file addition/deletion/changes at all!

I have already tried:

- `usePolling: true` option
- fs.watch
- node-watch library
- `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` environment variable

Nothing works.

Is it because COS is a different type of file system and these tools fail to monitor it? If so, What would then be the best available option for file watching in such scenario?

Comment: In the deployed environment, do you need (or want) live code reloading?  A generic Docker workflow would include all of the application code in an image, and when you wanted to upgrade the code, you'd build and integration-test a new image before deploying it.

Comment: No, I want to watch certain directories for new files being created/modified/moved or deleted.